# Is $q=37$ the only prime such that $qd$ and $q^2 d$ are base-$10$ palindromes, where $d = 9018009$?

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

Is $q=37$ the only prime such that $qd$ and $q^2 d$ are base-$10$ palindromes, where $d = 9018009$?

Note that
$$37d = 333666333$$
and
$${37}^2 d = 12345654321$$
when
$$d = 9018009 = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}.$$

I tried checking for $q \leq 101$ and found only $q=37$.

*Context*

**From the comments:** I came across this question while fiddling around with the only Descartes spoof that is known.

Comment: where did you find this quesiton? or how did you come up with it? it seems quite arbitrary without context :O

Comment: What a problem! If you don't have wonder in it, we can be sure that it has been computed that not other prime in a huge range.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I came across this question while fiddling around with the only Descartes spoof that is known.

Comment: Where does $d=9018009$ come from?, please.

Comment: @Piquito, you can try to Google for either *Descartes number* or *spoof odd perfect number*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking all $q$ from $0$ to $10^8$ with a Python program gives the following $(q,qd,q^2d)$ triples

```
d=9018009
def is_palindrom(n):
    s1=str(n) 
    return  s1==s1[::-1]
for q in range(100000000):
    if is_palindrom(q*d):
        if is_palindrom(q**2*d):
            print((q,q*d,q**2*d))
```

```
(0, 0, 0)
(37, 333666333, 12345654321)
(3367, 30363636303, 102234363432201)
(336367, 3033360633303, 1020322416142230201)
(366337, 3303630363033, 1210242036302420121)
(33336667, 300630363036003, 10022014302620341022001)
(33636367, 303333060333303, 10203022140604122030201)
(36663337, 330630303036033, 12122010222622201022121)
(36963037, 333333000333333, 12321000024642000012321)
```

another Python program generates and checks  numbers of a special structures

```
d=9018009
def is_palindrom(n):
    s1=str(n) 
    return  s1==s1[::-1]

h=3300
for t in range(30):
    q=h+67
    h+=63
    h*=100
    if is_palindrom(q*d):
        if is_palindrom(q**2*d):
            print(q)
```

```
3367
336367
33636367
3363636367
336363636367
33636363636367
3363636363636367
336363636363636367
33636363636363636367
3363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
3363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
336363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
33636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636367
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer, @miracle173!  Are all the numbers in your last list *primes*?

Comment: I take it back.  It appears that all the numbers in that last list are divisible by $37$.